# Changing data stored in a div using ajax and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Does anyone know a good guide or example for me to follow on how to change data on the screen using ajax?

I have a div that stores the last @event_status and every 5 minutes I want to go get the last event status created and display it in the div using ajax.

```
<div id="last_status">
    Last Status: 
    <% if @event_status.present? %>
        <span id="last_status_content">[<%= @event_status.user.initials %> @ <%= @event_status.created_at.strftime("%I:%M%p") %>]<br />
            Audio: <%= @event_status.audio ? 'Good' : 'None' %> |
            Video: <%= @event_status.video ? 'Good' : 'None' %> |
            <% if @event_status.notes.present? %>
                Notes: <%= @event_status.notes %>
            <% else %>
                Notes: No Notes
            <% end %>
        </span>
    <% else %>
        <span id="last_status_content">None</span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to periodically call an action and place the contents into a div. First extract the content of your last_status div to a partial, then return said partial from a controller action.

Javascript in your page:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('.last_status').load('/controller_name/action_name');
    }, 36000);
  }
);
```

Your controller action needs to then initialize all variables used by the partial, then render the partial.

```
def my_action
  @event_status = get_latest_event
  render :partial => 'my_partial'
end
```

Comment: Thank you quick and easy.  Exactly what I wanted.  Worked perfect.